# date-fns addBusinessdays but include predefined holiday-dates

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

So basicly I am trying to use `addBusinessDays(new Date(), 3)` which sets a startdate without taking weekends into account. However I need to make use of a list of dates ( holidays ) into this aswell. I can't find any documentation on how to add those holidays to the addBusinessDays.

I am using date-fns v2+

Example code:

```
import { addBusinessDays } from 'date-fns';

const holidays = [
  '2019-12-20'
]

console.log(addBusinessDays(new Date(), 3)) // should include holidays => 2019-12-24
```

Comment: Do no use the built–in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Since you're using date-fns, use [its parser](https://date-fns.org/v2.8.1/docs/parseISO).

Answer (score 0):

The function adds a specified number of business days based on the holidays and weekends for a given country, considering its timezone. It adjusts the final date and time to reflect 8:00 PM in the local timezone of the specified country and then converts this result back to UTC. This function is particularly useful for scenarios like calculating when a payment gateway will execute a payout, taking into account non-working days and timezone differences.

```
const Holidays = require('date-holidays');
const { addBusinessDays } = require('date-fns');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const ct = require('countries-and-timezones');

function addBusinessDaysWithHolidays(date, days, countryCode = 'MX') {
    const hd = new Holidays(countryCode);
    const countryInfo = ct.getCountry(countryCode);
    const timezone = countryInfo ? countryInfo.timezones[0] : 'UTC';
    let businessDaysAdded = 0;
    let currentDate = moment.tz(date, timezone);

    while (businessDaysAdded < days) {
        currentDate = moment.tz(addBusinessDays(currentDate.toDate(), 1), timezone);

        if (currentDate.day() !== 0 && currentDate.day() !== 6 && !hd.isHoliday(currentDate.toDate())) {
            businessDaysAdded++;
        }
    }

    currentDate.set({ hour: 20, minute: 0, second: 0 });

    return currentDate.tz('UTC');
}

// Usage Example
const startDate = new Date('2023-12-21T18:00:00Z');
const resultDate = addBusinessDaysWithHolidays(startDate, 3, 'MX');
console.log(`Final Result in UTC: ${resultDate.format()}`);
```

Answer (score -3):

You could perhaps do something like this?

```
const newHolidays = holidays.map(holiday => {
  return addBusinessDays(new Date(holiday), 3);
});

console.log(newHolidays);
```

**newHolidays -** This is a new array (leaving the original intact) containing each of the dates + 3 days

[Read about .map here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> .map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

You may want to also 'parse' the dates using date-fns as mentioned in the comments. You could do this like so:

```
function parseDates(dates) {
  return dates.map(date => {
    return parse(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", new Date());
  });
}

const parsedHolidays = parseDates(holidays);
```

Then you would want to change 'newHolidays' to similar to this:

```
const newHolidays = parsedHolidays.map(holiday => {
  return addBusinessDays(new Date(holiday), 3);
});
```

Or, you could move the parse function into the holidays.map if you'd prefer to parsed them one by one just before using addBusinessDays